# Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid date format when using Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I need to move table from an Azure SQL database to another database
Firstly, I have exported data from table by using below query:

```
select contract_id, contractor_name, plan_id, quantity, format(exec_date, 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff') as exec_date, initial_plan, contract_status, backup_disksize, format(register_date, 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff') as register_date, format(update_date, 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff') as update_date from [dbo].[contract_management]
```

And then, I have used a BCP query to import data to my new database:

```
bcp contract_management in Query3.csv -S dbaas-share-gs-sql.database.windows.net -d dbaas-tenant-gs-sqldb-tsdvdev01 -U owner_tsdvdev01 -P 12345678ABC-q -c -t ","
```

And this error happen

> SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid date format

I also tried other queries when export data like:

```
select contract_id, contractor_name, plan_id, quantity, format(exec_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as exec_date, initial_plan, contract_status, backup_disksize, format(register_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as register_date, format(update_date, 'yyyyMMdd') as update_date from [dbo].[contract_management]
```

But this error still happened.
What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless you're using "Native Format" files then the `bcp Utility` is really awful at moving data around between SQL Server instances. Because it has no knowledge of correct CSV encoding and decoding (ref: [RFC4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Seperated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)) it easily gets confused by field data that contains line breaks, quotes or commas. This causes it to lose sync and it attempts to write subsequent field data into the wrong columns. e.g.: Do any of your contractor names contain line breaks, quotes or comma characters?

Answer (score 0):

I believe **BCP** is unable to convert the format `yyyyMMddHHmmssffff` (which returns a value like this *202310310633130100*) to a `datetime`.  Try using this format in your export query instead:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff`

Comment: I've tried your solution, but there was still error :  SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid date format
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

Answer (score 0):

**The error is because when you export the data in the file it stored into the string format and when you import the data to table the table has column with data type datetime.**

To workaround this issue you need to Use a staging table (table with all datatype varchar for date time column of destination table), AFAIK You will not be able to import that date format directly into a `datetime2` column with bcp. After loading data into staging table then cast the data into date time format and insert into destination.

- Create staging table to store the date into varchar format

```sql
-- staging table to store the date into varchar format
CREATE TABLE ContractDetails (
    contract_id INT,
    contractor_name VARCHAR(255),
    plan_id INT,
    quantity INT,
    exec_date VARCHAR(20),  -- Assuming the format 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff'
    initial_plan VARCHAR(255),
    contract_status VARCHAR(50),
    backup_disksize INT,
    register_date VARCHAR(20),  -- Assuming the format 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff'
    update_date VARCHAR(20)     -- Assuming the format 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff'
);
```

- Insert the data from CSV file to this staging table.
  [image]
- Now insert the data from staging table to destination by converting to correct format.

```sql
insert into ContractDetails2
select 
contract_id, contractor_name, plan_id, quantity, 
CONVERT(Datetime, format(cast(SUBSTRING(exec_date,1,14) as numeric), '####-##-## ##:##:##')), 
initial_plan, contract_status, backup_disksize, 
CONVERT(Datetime, format(cast(SUBSTRING(exec_date,1,14) as numeric), '####-##-## ##:##:##')), 
CONVERT(Datetime, format(cast(SUBSTRING(exec_date,1,14) as numeric), '####-##-## ##:##:##')) 
from [dbo].[ContractDetails]
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [copying date values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-native-and-character-format-data-from-earlier-versions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#copying-date-values) in the documenation:

> bcp uses the ODBC bulk copy API. Therefore, to import date values into
> SQL Server, bcp uses the ODBC date format (yyyy-mm-dd
> hh:mm:ss[.f...]).

Use this T-SQL `FORMAT` function specification, assuming you need a precision of 4 like in your question:

```
FORMAT(exec_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff')
```

I successfully imported a text file with `datetime2` values in this format to Azure SQL Database with `bcp`.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but there was still error : SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid date format SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

Comment: My currently column is `datetime` column,  not `datetime2`

Comment: @NghiHoàngĐức, `datetime` supports a max precision of 3, with accuracy to 1/300 sec. I get different error when I try to import fractional seconds more than 3 with a `datetime` column: "Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding".

Comment: In addition to reducing the precision (`FORMAT(exec_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff')`), specify [-C 65001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#-c--acp--oem--raw--code_page-) if the file is utf-8 encoded, This will properly handle a byte order mark, if present.

Comment: I also tried format with 3 numbers percision, but error still happen

Comment: @NghiHoàngĐức, did you try the code page specification? I was able to repo your error with a utf-8 file that has a byte order mark. The error may also occur if the file format doesn't exactly match the table.